# How do I split mp4 files when Yamb fails?

Tags: windows, mp4

I have a 3.7G file from a flip that Yamb is not splitting ("Invalid IsoMedia File") even though I can play the file with both Windows Media Player and VLC.

Is there any other way to split this file?  It should not rely on mp4box.exe because that is what is failing.

Answer (score 1):

There's an answer here - [How do you split a large MPEG-4 video file into smaller files?](https://superuser.com/questions/35766/how-do-you-split-a-large-mpeg-4-video-file-into-smaller-files)

Comment: ffpmeg does not work on Windows easily.  mmpgui does not work for me at all.  So that link does not contain an answer.

Comment: ffmpeg works fine on Windows, but you can always use Super or meGui. http://sourceforge.net/projects/megui/ or http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html